# The value of root node(null value) didn't change after assigning a new node

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Currently, I am trying to writing linked list, but I encounter a problem.
When I execute the code below, it just print

> Current state:

So I use gdb and find that when I assigned "iHead = newNode" and return to main, the value of head didn't change!
Is the problem is relative to pass by value/reference or anyting else???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *nodePtr;
struct node{
    int value;
    nodePtr next;
};

void print(nodePtr);
void insert(nodePtr, int);


int main(void){
    nodePtr head = NULL;

    insert(head, 1);
    insert(head, 2);
    insert(head, 3);
    insert(head, 4);
    insert(head, 5);

    print(head);

    return 0; 
}

void print(nodePtr iHead){
    nodePtr ptr = iHead;

    printf("Current state:");
    while(ptr){
        printf("%d ", ptr->value);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insert(nodePtr iHead, int iValue){
    nodePtr newNode;

    newNode = (nodePtr) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->value = iValue;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(iHead == NULL)
        iHead = newNode;
    else{
        //find the last node
        nodePtr ptr = iHead;
        while(ptr -> next)
            ptr = ptr->next;

        //append new node
        ptr -> next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You need to pass `nodePtr *` to the insert function so it can overwrite the pointer in the calling function.  Alternatively, the insert function needs to return the new root node: `nodePtr insert(nodePtr root, int value)` called like `head = insert(head, 3);`. This is a very common problem; there are many other questions isomorphic to this one where the answer lies in one of the two alternatives.

Comment: C is call-by-value. Changing a function argument in a function does not modify it in the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing pass by value.

So the changes done within the function doesn't get reflected in main(). There are 2 ways to solving this.

1. `void insert(nodePtr *iHead, int iValue)`

Pass by reference to this function

2. `nodePtr insert(nodePtr iHead,int iValue)`

Make changes in the function and return HEAD

In `main()` have your list HEAD intact

```
nodePtr HEAD = insert(HEAD,2);
```